# Virtual Reality for all drivers

Tags: android, virtual-reality

I am implementing the exercise that comes in the documentation of virtual reality of how to implement a VR view:

> https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/sdk-simplepanowidget

I tested it with my Nexus 5 and it works fine but with a Motorola MotoG 3, I do not see the icon to be able to see it in the glasses of virtual reality and apart it does not move when you move the mobile.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the example work on any device, and how the scenario looks for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is debit for gyroscope sensor. If it's not present not runs well.